# Why i cant write the value of this variable c#

Tags: c#, double

I have a problem, i need the value of the 1(helyes variable)/3 but when I write it I get 0.

```
double szazalek;
szazalek = helyes / 3;
```

I dont get any error messages. My theory is the 1/3 is an infinity number and thats the reason why I can't write it. I tried the Math.Round bet the end was same.
Any help? :/
PS:I know my grammar is not the best my native language is not the english and I'm beginner with C#.

Comment: `helyes` is probably an int. Promote it to a double using a cast or write the literal 3 as `3d` and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Yes, helyes was int and i changed to double and now it works, thank you! :)